# how to place a resize image on a black layer, imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, layer

I would like to take a picture, resize it to 50% and put it on a black layer...
My issue is that resizing the image, resize the whole image (with the black layer too)and put it at the center of the new layer...
here's my code:

```
'convert -size 1920x1080 xc:Black  -gravity center image.png -resize 20% -composite -flatten result.png'
```

how could I do to just resize the image.png and not the whole layer ? 
thanks in advance
g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably want this:

```
convert image.png -resize 50% -gravity center -background black -extent 1920x1080 result.png
```

Or this, which is another way of doing the same thing:

```
convert -size 1920x1080 xc:black \( image.png -resize 50% \) -gravity center -composite result.png
```

Or, a more succinct version:

```
convert xc:black[1920x1080\!] \( image.png -resize 50% \) -gravity center -composite result.png
```

The first one resizes your image and then extends it with black from the centre outwards to your desired size.

The second creates the correctly sized canvas, then loads your image and  resizes it "on-the-side" in parentheses and composites the result onto the canvas.